# Server 2008 is asking for "microsoft.web.administration" in the GAC

Tags: windows-server-2008

On server 2008 how can I find "microsoft.web.administration" and load it into the GAC?

My program used to work but now it terminates complaining that it could not load "microsoft.web.administration".

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just referenced the control from the windows server 2008 SDK and it worked fine. Thanks.